# OnKeyEvent without focus in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-navigation

I am creating an app that makes use of a physical button on the device.

This button will have a different functionality depending on the screen that is active.

With Activities what I would do would be to have an Activity for each screen and in each one I would override the onKeyDown function. How would I do this with a single activity that navigates between different Jetpack Compose screens?
According to the Android documentation the correct way would be something like this...

```
Box(modifier = Modifier
    .onKeyEvent {
        Log.e("Pressed", it.nativeKeyEvent.keyCode.toString())
        true
    }
    .focusable()
    .fillMaxSize()
    .background(Color.Gray)
) {
    // All screen components
}
```

But this only works when one of the elements on the screen is focused and what I require is that it always works or not, is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One option is to keep the focus on the view so that the `Modifier.onKeyEvent` always works. Note that it may conflict with other focusable views, like `TextField`, so all these views should be children(at any level) of this always-focusable view.

```
val focusRequester = remember { FocusRequester() }
var hasFocus by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
Box(
    Modifier
        .focusRequester(focusRequester)
        .onFocusChanged {
            hasFocus = it.hasFocus
        }
        .focusable()
        .onKeyEvent {
            TODO()
        }
) {
}
if (!hasFocus) {
    LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
        focusRequester.requestFocus()
    }
}
```

---

Another option is to create compositional local handlers and pass events from your activity:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private val keyEventHandlers = mutableListOf<KeyEventHandler>()

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        setContent {
            CompositionLocalProvider(LocalKeyEventHandlers provides keyEventHandlers) {
                // your app
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onKeyDown(keyCode: Int, event: KeyEvent): Boolean {
        return keyEventHandlers.reversed().any { it(keyCode, event) } || super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event)
    }
}

val LocalKeyEventHandlers = compositionLocalOf<MutableList<KeyEventHandler>> {
    error("LocalKeyEventHandlers is not provided")
}

typealias KeyEventHandler = (Int, KeyEvent) -> Boolean

@Composable
fun ListenKeyEvents(handler: KeyEventHandler) {
    val handlerState = rememberUpdatedState(handler)
    val eventHandlers = LocalKeyEventHandlers.current
    DisposableEffect(handlerState) {
        val localHandler: KeyEventHandler = {
            handlerState.value(it)
        }
        eventHandlers.add(localHandler)
        onDispose {
            eventHandlers.remove(localHandler)
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
ListenKeyEvents { code, event ->
    TODO()
}
```